# How to union all, but separate the columns in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

The first query returns the data for the last 7 days, and returns 90 in total, while the second query returns data for the previous 7 days, returns 55 in total.

```
SELECT Market, count(*) AS This_week
FROM Buy_orders_SMA7_35_STAGE sma_tw
left JOIN SECTOR sec ON sec.Ticker = sma_tw.Name_buy
WHERE sma_tw.Date_buy >= date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 7 day) 
group by market

UNION ALL

SELECT Market, count(*) AS Last_week
FROM Buy_orders_SMA7_35_STAGE sma_lw
left JOIN SECTOR sec ON sec.Ticker = sma_lw.Name_buy
WHERE sma_lw.Date_buy >= date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 14 day) 
AND sma_lw.Date_buy < date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 7 day)
group by market
```

Current output is:

```
Market  This_week   
NULL     70 
OMXC25   6  
OMXO20GI 8  
OMXS30   6  
NULL     26 
OMXC25   21 
OMXO20GI 8
```

But the output should be:

```
Market  This_week   Last_week   Change
NULL     70            26        169.23%
OMXC25   6             21        -71.43%
OMXO20GI 8             8         0.00%
OMXS30   6             0         100.00%
```

Comment: You need to JOIN the subqueries, not UNION .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Market,
       SUM(sma.Date_buy >= date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 7 day)) AS This_week,
       SUM(sma.Date_buy >= date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 14 day) 
AND sma.Date_buy < date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 7 day)) as last_week,
       (1 - 
        SUM(sma.Date_buy >= date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 7 day)) /
        SUM(sma.Date_buy >= date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 14 day) 
AND sma.Date_buy < date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 7 day)) 
       ) as ratio
FROM Buy_orders_SMA7_35_STAGE sma left JOIN
     SECTOR sec 
     ON sec.Ticker = sma.Name_buy
WHERE sma.Date_buy >= date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 14 day) 
GROUP BY market;
```

Comment: some of your table aliases are wrong, and there's no need to repeat the where condition anywhere in the select fields

Comment: is ma_lw (which is supposed to be sma_lw) necessary alias, as we only use a single table?

Comment: also it does return  an error: 

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS This_week,
       SUM(ma_lw.Date_buy >= date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 14 d' at line 2

Comment: Allow me to insert the correct query, though the ratio part is wrong calculated. Just needs the fix the parenthesizes

Comment: @doomdaam . . . I fixed the query:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f4059a1e526f009e6964d392f65ed201.

Comment: Looks good! The ratio is not correctly calculated but i will fix that. It can be hard to do so without the data. Thank you!